# Smooth scroll on tablet and smartphones

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios

I'm working on a parallax website using the `stellar.js` plugin. The problem is that it makes the scroll "jittery". 
I managed to fix it on desktop browsers using a combination of `scrollTo` and `TweenMax` plugin:

```
$(function(){

    var $window = $(window);        //Window object

    var scrollTime = 1.2;           //Scroll time
    var scrollDistance = 170;       //Distance. Use smaller value for shorter scroll and greater value for longer scroll

    $window.on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(event){

        event.preventDefault(); 

        var delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta/120 || -event.originalEvent.detail/3;
        var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
        var finalScroll = scrollTop - parseInt(delta*scrollDistance);

        TweenMax.to($window, scrollTime, {
            scrollTo : { y: finalScroll, autoKill:true },
                ease: Power1.easeOut,   //For more easing functions see http://api.greensock.com/js/com/greensock/easing/package-detail.html
                autoKill: true,
                overwrite: 5                            
            });

    });

});
```

It works perfect but on tablets and smartphones the problem persists since `mousewheel DOMMouseScroll` are not device events. Any idea how can I solve this issue for these devices?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: which language you have used for the table/list view for Android and IOS app?